# Open Cart - Admin panel trouble

Tags: cpanel, opencart2.x

I have a problem with the admin panel of Open Cart.
I moved from localhost to online an opencart website.
Everything went fine except that the login page and admin panel add some Prefix text to the navigation menu and tabs title.

Check this image to see what it looks like:
[image: snapshot of my open cart admin panel]

If you have any ideas about this problem.
I did recheck all CONFIG.PHP files and they are filled with right information.

I dont know what to do actually....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like text is not being translated from language files.

Try to copy all files again , also make sure you have current language set in database. I also suggest to open "System -> Settings" in menu and check if language is selected menu and save those settings.

ALso check for any errors in OC error logs, apache error logs, or maybe in VQmod logs if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the soluition.

I did use a fres config.php file filed with my DIR and Database information and all came back to normal on the Admin cPanel.

Thanks